# How to write a bash script to calculate the md5 sum of the first n bytes of all files of a folder

Tags: bash, pipe, byte, md5

I basically have files in a folder for which I want to calculate the md5 sum. But since this would take very long I thought about just getting the first n bytes of each file and use this as input for calculating a md5 sum for each file.

If there are two files in a folder:

```
file1
file2
```

I want to run a script which outputs the following to the terminal:

```
file1 md5sum(first_n_bytes_of(./file1))
file2 md5sum(first_n_bytes_of(./file2))
```

I found several commands which kind of seem to achieve what I want but the piping does not work as intended:

```
ls | head -c 16 | md5sum

ls -> lists all files
head -c 16 -> get first 16 bytes of inputfile
md5sum -> calculate md5sum
```

I only get one MD5 value as output although I have more than one files in the folder where I run the script. There is also a dash which is not wanted / needed. The ouput looks like this:

```
6221d61df4fbe4b0f7da2d7e030ada7f  -
```

Also how to concatenate the md5sum at the end with the original provided filename?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the files, something like.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in *; do
   chksum="$(md5sum < <(head -c16 "$f") ) $f"
   echo "$chksum"
done
```

- `nullglob` the bash shell option that will not expand a literal glob `*` if there are no files in the current directory where you ran the script.
- `for f in *` loop through every files/folders in the current directory
  the `*` expands to that and `f` is the variable, see the output of `echo *`
- the `$( )` is called [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), it captures the value of whatever command is inside, it is often used to save a command in a variable like in this script, in this case the `chksum` is the variable
- `<( )` is called [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)
- To expand a variable in `bash` you need to add a `$` in front of it and 99.9 percent of the time you need quotes around it too.
- Basically the script just loops to all the files/folders in the current working directory and ran `md5sum` and `head` on each and every one of them and save the output in a variable and lastly `print()` in python terminology and `echo` or `printf` in bash.

Comment: This command does what I want but I how does it work? I am a beginner at using bash scripting. Advice on how to break down / read this command is appreciated :-)

Comment: I think I marked the question as answered? Upvoting was recorded but is not visible due to my reputation on stackoverflow. Thank you for answering and explaining my question!

Comment: This script fails if a file contains a single quote character e.g. file'name.txt with a lot of errors: **xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option**. How to fix the script?

Comment: I did not use `xargs` in this answer, since xargs is broken by default, how can I fix something that I did not even use in this script? I do not know/see the script and you're asking me to fix it? There is nothing about xargs in your post...

Comment: I used this script. I don't know if I messed something up in my system maybe but if I run this script and I have a file with a single quote in the filename the terminal gets a lot of these error messages. Did you try this case?

Comment: The solution I have posted can handle any kind of quotes in the filenames.

Comment: Does it work for a filename with a single quote for you?